# Angular 2 ionic 2 cordova sms plugin for ios fails to render send part in messages app

Tags: ios, iphone, angular, cordova, ionic2

I'm using https://github.com/cordova-sms/cordova-sms-plugin to send text message on ios.

The code is fairly simple :

```
handler: () => {
            console.log('send text clicked');
            var options = {
            replaceLineBreaks: false, // true to replace \n by a new line, false by default
           };
            SMS.send('1234567890', 'my message', options).then(
              (result) => {
                alert('sent')
              }, (error) => {

              });

          }
```

This opens the messages app on my ios device (iphone 7 plus).

However, the messages app in this case does not render the footer area which shows text section and send button, and hence I cannot send the message.

Comment: anyone on this?

Comment: Same thing for me, have you found a solution?

Comment: i think i saw it fixed sort of magically after some days